# FXML object getting deleted before its used

Tags: java, javafx, garbage-collection, javafx-8, fxml

Here is my code

```
@FXML
public ScrollPane mainScrollPane;
@FXML
public Label dateScrollerLabel;
@FXML
public HBox calendarContainer;

int x = 5;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    scene = JavaFXUtils.createScene(1000, 600, "Main.fxml", this);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/assets/resources/icon/icon_256.png")));
    primaryStage.setTitle("HWP");
    primaryStage.show();

    //*****//
    scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, this::keyPressed);
}

public void initialize() {
    System.out.println(x); // not null
    System.out.println(calendarContainer); // not null
    currentSchedule = new Schedule(mainScrollPane, dateScrollerLabel, calendarContainer); // no nullpointer exception
}

private void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    switch (keyEvent.getCode()) {
        case A:
            System.out.println(x); // not null
            System.out.println(calendarContainer); // null
            currentSchedule = new Schedule(mainScrollPane, dateScrollerLabel, calendarContainer); // nullpointer exception
            break;
    }
}
```

I am able to run the following line without any errors in the `initialize()` method:

```
currentSchedule = new Schedule(mainScrollPane, dateScrollerLabel, calendarContainer);
```

However, when I run the same exact code afterward, in the `keyPressed()` method, there is a nullpointer exception thrown. It seems as if `calendarContainer` became null at some point between `initialize()` and `keyPressed`. I checked my code and at no point in my program do I change the value of `calendarContainer` or re-assign it, it is only created in the FXML file.

```
<HBox fx:id="calendarContainer" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" styleClass="calendarContainer" />
```

Why does the FXML object get deleted (maybe a trigger-happy garbage collecter?) but the int does not?

Comment: `calendarContainer` is only initialized in the controller. It is not initialized in the `Application ` instance that is created when you launch the application, which is the object on which `start()` is called.

Comment: Basically, it's too confusing when you use the same class both for the `Application` and for the controller. Create a different class for the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `Application` class as the controller class: it makes it too difficult to keep track of which fields are initialized in which instances of the class.

> Why does the FXML object get deleted

It doesn't.

Fields annotated `@FXML` are only initialized in the controller. When you load the FXML file, the `FXMLLoader` creates an instance of the class specified by the `fx:controller` attribute, creates the objects corresponding to the elements in the FXML, and then sets the fields *in the controller* to the objects it created. Finally, it calls `initialize()` on the controller.

So in this case, `calendarContainer` is initialized in the controller (which is why you see a non-null value in your `initialize()` method), but it is never initialized in the instance of the `Application` class, on which `start()` is called. So it doesn't suddenly become null at some point: it was always null.

You should create a separate class for the controller:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ScrollPane mainScrollPane;
    @FXML
    private Label dateScrollerLabel;
    @FXML
    private HBox calendarContainer;

    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println(x); // not null
        System.out.println(calendarContainer); // not null
        currentSchedule = new Schedule(mainScrollPane, dateScrollerLabel, calendarContainer); // no nullpointer exception
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        switch (keyEvent.getCode()) {
            case A:
                System.out.println(x); // not null
                System.out.println(calendarContainer); // null
                currentSchedule = new Schedule(mainScrollPane, dateScrollerLabel, calendarContainer); // nullpointer exception
                break;
        }
    }  

}
```

(and update the `fx:controller` attribute in the FXML file).

Now you `Application` class can do:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // Not sure what this does, but you probably can't use it without some
        // modification.
        // scene = JavaFXUtils.createScene(1000, 600, "Main.fxml", this);

        // assuming path is correct:
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load(), 1000, 600);

        Controller controller = loader.getController();
        scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, controller::keyPressed);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/assets/resources/icon/icon_256.png")));
        primaryStage.setTitle("HWP");
        primaryStage.show();


    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, I get that it was initialized in the controller. But after it has been initialized, shouldn't it stay with that same value in the Application class?

Comment: @A.S. What do you mean "stay initialized "? You have two objects. Each one has a `calendarContainer` field. Only one of those fields is ever initialized, the other is *always* null.

Comment: But I got it to work by separating the classes so thanks :)